# When scrolling on ios 14 safari the image disappears and a grey background appears

Tags: html, css, ios, ios14

When scrolling on ios 14 safari the images and text disappears and a grey background appears.
I think this only happens on newer iphones because there was no problem on my iphone 7. Also this cannot be reproduced in android or a desktop browser. I am wondering what can cause this problem on the newer iphones(X and above).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, for me removing `background-attachment: fixed` solved this issue on iOS. Note that this makes it where the content no longer scrolls across the background, but for me this was not an issue.